# Multiple click events are executed when multiple angularjs directives used on a page

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, echarts

I am trying to execute some logic in a controller when click `event` happens in a directive (chart). Specifically, I want to capture `event data` to understand what user clicked on in a chart and filter other charts by this (cross-filtering between charts).

After I added click `event handler` in directive, I see that click `event` is executed two times (by the number of charts on a page). I tried different things to resolve it on my own (unbind click before bind click, destroy directive), none of it worked.

Here's my directive code:

```
function dmChart(datamatic, $timeout) {
var directive = {
  link: link,
  restrict: 'EA',
  scope: {
    chartId: '@',
    data: '=',
    height: '=',
    width: '=?'
  }
};
return directive;

function link(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
  var chart = null;

  function initChart() {
    chart = datamatic.chart(scope.chartId, {
      width: scope.width ? scope.width : 680,
      height: scope.height ? scope.height : 450
    });
    chart.render(element[0]).then(function(){
      chart.setData(scope.data);
      chart.on("click", function(ev) {
        scope.$emit('chart.click', ev);
      });
      registerWatch();
    })
  }

  $timeout(function(){
    initChart();
  }, 0);

  function registerWatch() {
    scope.$watch('data', function(newVal, oldVal) {
      if (typeof newVal !== 'undefined') {
        $timeout(function(){
          chart.setData(scope.data);
        }, 0);
      }
    });
  }


}
```

Here's a fiddle, where the issue is reproducing?
https://jsfiddle.net/7nzLtc5h/